# MongoDB connecting Prisma stuck

Tags: mongodb, prisma

I am trying to connect MongoDB Atlas with Prisma schema with calling the .env variables and I tried a few days there is also DNS error 10051. However, even I allowed access from anywhere in the IP address, the error still could not be fixed. Can anyone show some good solutions in order to successfully connect prisma with MongoDB?